# Creating and saving a GlobalSet element type in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, migration, elementquery

The following code is in a migration. It runs fine and there are no errors and prints `SAVED`, but nothing is saved in the `globalsets` database table.

All my other content migrations run fine so it is not a DB issue.

```
    $globalConfig = [
      "type" => \craft\elements\GlobalSet::class,
      "settings" => [
        "name" => "Meta",
        "handle" => "meta"
      ],
    ];

    $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->createElement($globalConfig);

    if (Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($element)) {
        print "SAVED";
    }
```

Why is this not saving ?

Comment: After you call `saveElement()`, does `$element->getErrors()` return anything?

Comment: @BradBell getErrors is just an empty array. Do I also need to save a field layout first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

So I looked in the craft core to see how the CP does it. Turns out we have to use this

```php
$gs = new \craft\elements\GlobalSet();
$gs->name = "Meta";
$gs->handle = "meta";

Craft::$app->getGlobals()->saveSet($gs);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Craft core reference

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/GlobalsController.php#L55-L96